# How should i package this game as an apk?

Tags: java, android, pygame, apk

I created a game in python and i tried to package it as an apk. After many unsuccessful attempts, i tried to install android studio and recreate it in java. As a first try to code in java i have errors that i don't know how to overcome

I tried using kivy and briefcase to package my game as an apk and then i would have only changed the inputs. But i gave up this solution and instead tried to recreate it in java without much success.

```
import pygame
import random
from os import path
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
#image = pygame.image.load("grass.png").convert_alpha()
#image = pygame.transform.scale(image,(500,500))
#dim = image.get_rect()
#win.blit(image,(250-dim.center[0],250-dim.center[1]))
pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.set_caption("F1")
if not path.exists("highscore.txt"):
    f = open("highscore.txt","w")

run = False
out = False

while out == False:

    myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 18)
    hsc = myFont.render("Highscore:", 1, [255,255,255])
    f = open("highscore.txt", "r")
    highsc = myFont.render(f.read(), 1, [255,255,255])

    x = 238
    y = 500
    width = 30
    height = 50
    speed = 0
    hs = 0

    obstacles = []


    while not run :
        start = pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,125,125),[200,125,100,30])
        getout = pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,125,125),[200,325,100,30])
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1 :
                if start.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    run = True
                elif getout.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    pygame.quit()


    class incoming(object):
        def __init__(self,a,b,width,height):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b + speed
            self.width = width
            self.height = height

        def collision(self):
            if x == self.a and self.b + height > 380:
                if self.b < 380 + height:
                    return True

        def draw(self,win):
            pygame.draw.rect(win,(random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255),random.randrange(0,255)),(self.a,self.b,self.width,self.height))
            #inc = pygame.image.load("inc.png").convert_alpha()
            #inc = pygame.transform.scale(inc,(30,50))
            #if self.a < 235:
               # inc = pygame.transform.flip(inc,180,1)
            #win.blit(inc,(self.a,self.b))


    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+2, random.randrange(600,800))

    while run:
        win.fill((0,255,0))
        road = pygame.draw.rect(win,[0,0,0],[165,y,140,-1000000])
        cont = pygame.draw.rect(win,[255,255,255],[234,1000000,2,-1000000])
        pl = pygame.draw.rect(win,[255,0,0],[x,380,width,height])
        #player1 = pygame.image.load("enzo.png").convert_alpha()
        #player1 = pygame.transform.scale(player1,(30,50))
        #win.blit(player1,(x,380))



        a = random.randrange(168,276,35)

        while speed < 30:
            speed = speed + 3
            break

        y=y+speed

        b = 0

        Score = int((y - 500)/100)
        myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 18)

        scris = myFont.render("Score:", 1, [255,255,255])
        scr = myFont.render(str(int(Score)), 1, [255,255,255])

        win.blit(scris, (30,40))
        win.blit(scr, (30, 60))


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+2 and speed > 1.3  :
                obstacles.append(incoming(a,b,width,height))


        for obstacle in obstacles:
            if obstacle.collision():
                pygame.time.delay(1000)
                win.set_alpha(0)
                run = False
                with open("highscore.txt", "r+") as hisc:
                    hi = hisc.read()
                    if not hi:  
                        hi = '0'
                    if int(Score) > int(hi):
                        hisc.seek(0)  
                        hisc.write(str(int(Score)))



            if obstacle.a < 210:
                obstacle.b = obstacle.b + speed + 1
            else:
                obstacle.b = obstacle.b + speed - 1
            obstacle.draw(win)


        win.blit(hsc, (380,40))
        win.blit(highsc, (380, 60))

        pygame.display.update()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 200 :
            x=x-35

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 260:
            x=x+35


pygame.quit()
```

THIS (Above) IS HOW THE GAME SHOULD WORK IN PYTHON.

THIS (Below) IS MY CODE IN JAVA

```
package com.example.neonrace;

import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolean run = false;
        boolean out = false;

        while (out == false){
            final int x = 238;
            final int[] y = {500};
            final int width = 30;
            final int height = 50;
            final int[] speed = {0};

            final List<Object> obstacles = new ArrayList<Object>();

            class incoming{
                int a;
                int b;
                int width;
                int height;

                public incoming(int a, int b, int width, int height){
                    this.a = a;
                    this.b = b;
                    this.width = width;
                    this.height = height;
                }

                public void collision;{
                    if (x == this.a) && (this.b + height) > 380; {
                        if (this.b < (380 + height));{
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                public static void draw() {
                    Canvas.drawRect(this.a, this.b, this.width, this.height, black);
                }
            };

            new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                    new java.util.TimerTask(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            obstacles.add(incoming(int a, int b, int width, int height));
                            obstacles[].draw();
                        }
                    },700
            );




            Button Start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);
            Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                boolean run = true;
                while (run) {
                    Canvas.drawRect(165, 380, 240, 250, blue);
                    Canvas.drawRect(x,382, 30,50, red);

                    Random r = new Random();
                    int a = (int) r.nextInt(168, 276, 35);

                    while (speed[0] <30){
                        speed[0] = speed[0] + 3;
                    }

                    y[0] = y[0] + speed[0];

                    int size = ArrayList.size();
                    int i = 0;

                    for ( int i = 0, i < size, i++){
                        if obstacles[i].collision == true{
                            run = false
                        }

                        if obstacles[i].a < 210{
                            obstacles[i].b += speed+1
                        }
                        else {
                            obstacles[i].b += speed - 1
                        }
                        obstacles[i].draw()
                    }

                    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                        int u = (int) event.getX();
                        if u < 200{
                            x = x - 35
                        }
                        else {
                            x = x + 35
                        }
                        }
                    }



                }

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the first time that i code in java and the result is far from the expected one. 
P.S. I know i hadn't done anything about the quit button. This should be the last thing to worry about.

Comment: if you want, you can use an IDE like android studio to code your game. It would really help you with the front end and backend and the connection between both.

Answer (score 0):

You're not putting this anywhere near the format needed for an Android app.  You can't have a big loop running forever in onCreate-  onCreate needs to return fairly quickly.  And until it does, you won't see any UI.  You're making  calls to Canvas.drawRect-  that won't work, drawRect is called on an instance of a Canvas, not on the class.  And an Activity doesn't get a draw function-  it has views, and those views get to draw.  An activity doesn't.

Honestly, this is at the level where you need to step back, study Android and Java, and try again when you've learned more.  It would be faster to rewrite than salvage.